# Accessing Google Secret Manager from AI Platform training job with custom container

Tags: python, google-cloud-ml

I am trying to access a secret stored in [Google Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs) from an AI Platform Training job that runs in a custom container. I am using the following Python code to retrieve secrets:

```py
# Standard library imports
import os

# Import the Secret Manager client library.
from google.cloud import secretmanager


def access_secret_version(secret_id, version_id, project_id=os.environ.get("GCP_PROJECT")):
     # Create the Secret Manager client.
    client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()

    # Build the resource name of the secret version.
    name = client.secret_version_path(project_id, secret_id, version_id)

    # Access the secret version.
    response = client.access_secret_version(name)

    # Return the secret payload.
    return response.payload.data.decode("UTF-8")
```

I have added the `Secret Manager Secret Accessor` role to the default Cloud ML service account (`service-XXX@cloud-ml.google.com.iam.gserviceaccount.com`), but access is still denied:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
```

Have I granted the correct role to the correct service account or I am missing something else?

Answer (score 0):

We have an alpha feature to enable your use case. Can you send us an email to cloudml-feedback@google.com please?

Comment: The feature has been in beta now. https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/custom-service-account

Comment: Does your comment then imply that the only way to access Secret Manager via ML Engine is via specifying another service account to run as for training jobs (as per your link)? And that giving the role `Secret Manager Secret Accessor` to the `...@cloud-ml.google.com.iam.gserviceaccount.com` service account will never work?

Comment: We are running training jobs via Google Composer DAGs, and it seems that one cannot do a service account impersonation through the MLEngine operator  using `delegate_to` when using automatic authentication within Composer, as per https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/8163

Comment: Any advice on how we can access Secret Manager from an ML Engine/AI Platform training job, when that job is being submitted through Google Composer?

Comment: In the job creation request sending to ML Engine, you can specify the service account you want to use. Note that this service needs to have access to Secret Manager.